# Изображение во весь экран

Tags: html, css

Скажите, как сделать так, чтобы независимо от размера монитора, изображение всегда полностью занимало весь экран и не приходилось прокручивать его вниз, как в данный момент у меня? код такой:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Изображения по вертикали</title>
  <style>
   .center {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="left">
    <img src="line1.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%" >
   <a href="page2.htm"><img src="line2.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%"></a>
   <a href="page2.htm"><img src="line3.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%"></a>
   <a href="index.htm"><img src="line4.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%"></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: img {position:fixed;} ?

Comment: У вас код CSS неправильный 50% повторяется 4 раза а по идее всего 100% т.е 4 раза по 25% (а не 50% как у вас)!

Comment: У меня одни только вопрос где-ты там увидел 50%?)

Comment: <img src="line1.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%" >
   <a href="page2.htm"><img src="line2.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%"></a>
   <a href="page2.htm"><img src="line3.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%"></a>
   <a href="index.htm"><img src="line4.jpg"  width="100%" height="50%"></a> Возможно, про это?

Comment: Так это и не мой код)

Comment: [Как насчет?](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bugmenot/jTUd3/5/show/)

Comment: А чей это код и скажите вы решили свою проблему? (Смогли сделать как хотели с картинками?)

Comment: это мой код! проблема так и висит( и про 25% я не понял...просто если я по высоту по 25 поставлю, тогда общее изображение будет несколько сплющено) придется менять ширину, а это уже будет подгонка под разрешение экрана(

Answer (score 3):

Сделай фоном:

```
body{
    height:100%;
    background:url('../img/bg1.jpg') center top no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Вот попробуй:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Изображения по вертикали</title>
  <style>
    table{
        border:1px solid red;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    table tr td{
        height:25%;
        width:100px;
        border:1px solid blue;
        background:url('bg.gif') left top no-repeat;
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }
    table tr td a{
    height:25%;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td> <a href="page2.htm"></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="page2.htm"></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="index.htm"></a></td></tr>
  </div>
  </table>
```

Comment: так у меня 4 изображения и три из них являются ссылками...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - есть плагин [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body{padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;height:100%}
#bg{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%}
#content{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1}
</style>

<img src="bg.jpg" alt="" id="bg" />
<div id="content">...</div>
```

Только предупреждаю сразу: картинка будет выглядеть страшно.